# Next.js Service Worker 404 error in production build only

Tags: next.js, service-worker

Using Next 12.2.4

I have a very simple service worker js file (/public/sw.js) added to the public directory in nextjs.

```js
//sw.js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function () {
    return;
});
```

It is being registered in the _app.tsx as below:

```js
//_app.tsx
export default class MyApp extends App {
    componentDidMount() {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
            window.addEventListener('load', () =>
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(
                    (registration) =>
                        console.log(
                            'Service Worker registration successful with scope: ',
                            registration.scope
                        ),
                    (err) => console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err)
                )
            );
    }

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

when I run in development mode it is served, and lighthouse tool shows the pwa icon correctly.

However when I make production build the sw.js file is absent, and I get a 404 error when i try to access it.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured out the issue.

My Next.js solution is an older solution upgraded to the latest version 12.

It used the older convention of having a static folder inside the public folder for assets like images etc.

As the static folder has been deprecated in versions 9+ it was the one causing an issue.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-dir-deprecated

I had to move out all my other folders from static one level back into public folder, and after that the build was correctly exposing public/sw.js in the final build.